# General questions about a tcp server client connection via sockets in Java

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, server, client

1. I have a server and a client in two different Networks. These are supposed to send each other messages. I know that the server needs to have port forwarding set up for his computer and his router. Does the client need to do that aswell?
2. Is it correct to use a DataInputStream and a PrintStream on both client and server side to send messages?
3. If I use this code on the server side:

   ServerSocket server1 = new ServerSocket(Port);

   server1.bind(new InetSocketAddress(ip, Port1));

What do I need to enter for Port, ip and Port1?

Comment: The Java Tutorial has a good chapter on [sockets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html).

Comment: Port forwaring is not a java issue. This is pure network configuration. Usually there is no need to bind the server socket explicitely. It's just enough to open the server through constructor which whill let it listen on the given Port.